# How to use two types of parameters within a function?

Tags: javascript

I call the following function to create a new css object:

```
set(
    dot, { 
        x: mX,  
        y: mY, 
        force3D: !0 
    }
);


set: function(el) {
    alert(el);

    var dot = $(el).css('-webkit-transform', 'translate3d(' + x + ', ' + y + ', ' + z + ')');
    return dot;
}
```

Now I was wondering how to get the first parameter of the function set, to be more precise: dot.

I already tried: `alert(el);` but this will give me an alert with [object Object]. I know you can access the object options by using `el.x`, but how to access the first parameter I doesn't know.

Comment: `el === dot`. You're seeing `[object Object]` because `alert` converts it to a string. Do `console.log(el)` and open your console (F12 on Window,s Opt+Cmd+I on OSX)

Comment: That is working yeah. Only when I add all the parameters to console log the last 3 (from the object) will be undefined: `console.log(el, el.x, el.y, el.z);`

Comment: Am I missing something here? `arguments[0]` is `el`, `arguments[1].x` is your `x`, etc. [See docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Comment: What do you mean by that? I doesn't use arguments, so..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You say you don't know how to access the first parameter but it looks like you do so your question is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```js
set = function(el) {
    console.log(el.x); // You can access the properties like this
    console.log(el.y);
    console.log(el.force3D);
    
    return dot;
};

// Build the params
var dot = {
    x: 'asdf',
    y: 'asdf',
    force3D: !0
};

// Call the set() method
set(dot);
```

Answer (score 1):

I must be missing something, but if you're trying to access what you're sending, just name a formal parameter:

```js
set = function(el, params) {
    var dot = $(el).css('-webkit-transform', 'translate3d(' + params.x + ', ' + params.y + ', ' + params.z + ')');
    return dot;
}

set(dot, { x:1.0, y:2.1, z:0.1 });
```

Or use [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) if you don't want formal named parameters.